# Storing large file in array is not possible?

Tags: perl

There is a process which stores the file in an array. Unfortunately when the file is too big (Let's say 800K lines or more than 60 MB) an error is returned like "Out of memory!". Is there any solution to this? For example the following code throw "Out of memory!".

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

die unless (open (INPUT, "input.txt"));
@file=<INPUT>;                     # It fails here 
print "File stored in array\n";    # It never reaches here
$idx=0;
while ($idx < @file) {
    $idx++;
}
print "The line count is = $idx\n";
```

Comment: describe more of what you are actually doing and you will get a much better answer

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `Tie::File` for that:

```
use Tie::File;
my @file

tie @file, 'Tie::File', "input.txt";

print "File reflected in array\n";
print "The line count is ", scalar(@file);
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, you don't need to read in the whole file at once. The readline operator returns only one line at a time when called in scalar context:

```
1 while <INPUT>;   # read a line, and discard it.
say "The line count is = $.";
```

The `$.` special variable is the line number of the last read filehandle.

---

#### Edit: Line counting was just an example

Perl has no problem with large arrays, it just seems that your system doesn't have enough memory. Be aware that Perl arrays use more memory than C arrays, as a scalar allocate additional memory for flags etc, and because arrays grow in increasing steps.

If memory is an issue, you have to transform your algorithm from one that has to load a whole file into memory to one that only keeps one line at a time.

Example: Sorting a multi-gigabyte file. The normal approach `print sort <$file>` won't work here. Instead, we sort portions of the file, write them to tempfiles, and then switch between the tempfiles in a clever way to produce one sorted output:

```
use strict; use warnings; use autodie;

my $blocksize = shift @ARGV; # take lines per tempfile as command line arg

mkdir "/tmp/$$";  # $$ is the process ID variable

my $tempcounter = 0;
my @buffer;
my $save_buffer = sub {
    $tempcounter++;
    open my $tempfile, ">", "/tmp/$$/$tempcounter";
    print $tempfile sort @buffer;
    @buffer = ();
};
while (<>) {
  push @buffer, $_;
  $save_buffer->() if $. % $blocksize == 0;
}
$save_buffer->();

# open all files, read 1st line
my @head =
  grep { defined $_->[0] }
  map { open my $fh, "<", $_; [scalar(<$fh>), $fh] }
  glob "/tmp/$$/*";

# sort the line-file pairs, pick least
while((my $least, @head) = sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } @head){
  my ($line, $fh) = @$least; print $line;

  # read next line
  if (defined($line = <$fh>)){
    push @head, [$line, $fh];
  }           
}

# clean up afterwards
END {
  unlink $_ for glob "/tmp/$$/*";
  rmdir "/tmp/$$";
}
```

Could be called like `$ ./sort-large-file 10000 multi-gig-file.txt >sorted.txt`.

This general approach can be applied to all kinds of problems. This is a “divide and conquer” strategy: If the problem is too big, solve a smaller problem, and then combine the pieces.

Comment: The above code is for example only. Requirement is to store large files in array, because it performs some other actions. Eg - A process reads more than 200000 txt files, based on some conditions it filters out some lines and then aggregate all to one file. Each of the files is stored in a single array (Overwrite array after the file is completely read and action is performed with next file). The problem occurs when one of these files before aggregation is already very large (more than 60 MB). It can't be stored in an array or what? Only solution is needed for how to store a big file in array?

Comment: so that says you want the output in an array, but why do you need the input in an array rather than reading one line at a time?